# Is it possible to cast Oracle User Defined Types (UDT) as byte[]/blob in ODP.NET?

Tags: c#, oracle, odp.net, odp.net-managed

Our .NET application uses ODP.NET with SDO_GEOMETRY which is a UDT for spatial functionality.
Currently only the Oracle Unmanaged Driver supports UDT for use in ODP.NET.
Although it looks like [UDT support is definitely on the ODP.NET team's radar](https://github.com/oracle/dotnet-db-samples/issues/56).

What I'm wondering is if there is a manual way to convert in and out of UDT based on a byte[] etc.
I know in the link I posted above that people are using WKT as a workaround, but we'd also be willing to entertain the idea of writing our own adapters for C# SDO Geometry, SDO_Point, etc. that have something like `ToBytes()` and `FromBytes()` if they could be used in a query.

Is it possible to cast the SHAPE attribute as a BLOB and then write some C# to deserialize it?
Perhaps you would have to write your own PL/SQL functions to convert BLOBS to SDO_Geometry?

Because of the convenience of the managed driver, we would like to be able to use it, so we don't have to compile against multiple versions of the unmanaged driver and work within client environments that all have varying unmanaged client configurations.

The last fallback would be to pick one version of Oracle client and just require the customer to have that version of the unmanaged client installed, but they'd need to be aware of any gotchas that come with multiple side-by-side installations (PATH, GAC, machine.config, etc.)

Comment: procedure/function-wrapping the UDT=>byte would require quite a bit of pl/sql-programming, but should work without environment-dependencies (*you* define your byte-structure and implement the conversion). if the data-sets are huge probably worth the effort. but if sdo_geometry is not large you could convert to xml (which is easy out-of-the box) "XMLTYPE(sdo_geometry_var).getstringval" in the wrapper

Comment: I've used xml to pass complex structures. Not sure is Oracle has JSON parser for the similar function

Comment: @MichaelHauptmann thanks for the suggestion. that makes sense about 'you' defining the byte structure and conversion. I didn't know XMLTYPE existed either. That might make for a quicker coding effort, but as you mentioned, if the geometry objects are huge, it could be worth considering another solution. Appreciate the thoughts!

Comment: spatial should be huge by nature ... didn´t work with that kind of data. maybe https://blogs.oracle.com/author/tom-kyte / https://asktom.oracle.com or http://stevenfeuersteinonplsql.blogspot.com/ can put in some thought about memory-issues in this kind of conversion (or did in the past)

Comment: Just got done with a POC. I changed my select statement to convert the sdo_geometry to the WKB (well-known binary) format using sdo_util.to_wkbgeometry(...) and sdo_util.from_wkbgeometry(...)  and it turns out we already had code to convert WKB format into objects we can work with. Thanks for the suggestion, worked nicely!